# Is item1, 2, 3 still relevant in flutter?

Tags: flutter, quill, delta

I am trying to listen to an event in my app (this app includes quill editor, flutter)

```
_controller!.document.changes.listen((event) {
      if(event.item3 == quill.ChangeSource.LOCAL){
        
      }
}
```

Instead I am getting the error -> item3 is not defined

my question is, is item1, 2 and 3 still relevant?